# What is the scriptural basis for a monarchical episcopate?

Tags: catholicism, biblical-basis, eastern-orthodox, bishops, church-hierarchy

What scriptural basis has traditionally been put forth by the Catholic and the Orthodox Churches to support the idea of monarchical episcopate (the idea that there must be only one bishop over a city or a region)?

Comment: cf. [The Church Always Had Monarchical Bishops: A Response to James White](http://www.biblicalcatholic.com/apologetics/a80.htm).

Comment: @user13992 That looks like an answer waiting to be made.

Comment: Perhaps also of interest:  [*One City, One Bishop, One Church*](http://www.orthodoxytoday.org/articles6/HilarionOneBishop.php), by the Russian Orthodox Bishop Hilarion Alfayev

Comment: What is the Scriptural basis for there being more than one bishop over a given city?

Comment: The [monarchic Trinity](http://www.ancientfaith.com/podcasts/hopko/the_holy_trinity).

Comment: @Lucian - Are you sure that link is relevant? How is the matter of Trinity related to the monarchial episcopate?

Comment: @brilliant: How is God related to religion ? (Is that even a question ?)

Comment: @Lucian - Unless I have misunderstood something, episcopate can be  monarchial or non-monarchial regardless of whether the God is perceived as Three-One or as One. And as for how God is related to religion, God is certainly related to it if only because religion is the body of humans who want to be close to God.

Comment: @brilliant: Many combinations are indeed possible; the question is, which one makes more sense or fits better with the other tenets of the faith.

Answer (score 3):

The scriptural basis on which Catholicism support the church polity of monarchial episcopate are the following scriptural passages:

### Acts 21:18

> On the following day Paul went in with us to **James, and all the
> elders were present**-(*ESV*)

In Catholicism, being an elder and being a bishop are two different offices.Futhermore, in Catholicism, St. James was believed to be a bishop. Therefore, Acts 21:18 is an explicit Bible verse that supports monarchial episcopate when understood in terms of overall Catholic teachings.

### Titus 1:5

> This is why I left **you** in Crete, so that **you** might put what
> remained into order, and **appoint elders** in every town as I
> directed **you**—(*ESV*)

Catholics believe that bishoprick and eldership aren't the same.Catholics believe that St. Titus was a bishop.In this verse, St. Titus appoints elders. In Catholicism, appointing elders is the function of a bishop.When read in Catholic lenses, Titus 1:5 is an another Bible verse that clearly supports monarchial episcopacy.

### 1 Timothy 5:17-22

> Let the elders who rule well be considered worthy of double honor,
> especially those who labor in preaching and teaching. 18 For the
> Scripture says, “You shall not muzzle an ox when it treads out the
> grain,” and, “The laborer deserves his wages.” 19 Do not
> admit(you-singular) a charge against an elder except on the evidence
> of two or three witnesses. 20 As for those who persist in sin, rebuke
> (you-singular) them in the presence of all, so that the rest may stand
> in fear. 21 In the presence of God and of Christ Jesus and of the
> elect angels I charge **you** to keep these rules without prejudging,
> doing nothing from partiality. 22 Do not be hasty in the laying on of
> hands(you-singular), nor take part in the sins of others; keep
> yourself pure -(*ESV*).

St. Timothy is a bishop according to Catholicism.In this text, he possesses exclusive authority over the Ephesian elders.1 Timothy 5:17-22 supports monarchial episcopacy when read in light of Catholic theology.

### Conclusion

Ample scriptural passages provided cogent biblical evidence for monarchial episcopate. This is only true when read in light of Catholic interpretation of eldership and bishoprick, though.

---

References:

http://www.biblicalcatholic.com/apologetics/a80.htm

http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/02581b.htm

Answer (score 3):

[St. Robert Bellarmine](https://www.encyclopedia.com/people/history/italian-history-biographies/robert-bellarmine#block-views-block-subcategories-for-category-block-2)'s *De Romano Pontifice* ([***On the Roman Pontiff***](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=5349)), recently [translated into English for the first time](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=5349), treats the question "Should the Ecclesiastical Government be a Monarchy?" in book 1, chapters 5 through 9:

5. The Second Question is Proposed; Should the Ecclesiastical Government be a Monarchy?
6. That the Government of the Church Should not be a Democracy
7. That Ecclesiastical Government Should not be in the Power of Secular Princes
8. That Ecclesiastical Government Should not be Chiefly in the Power of Bishops
9. Why the Ecclesiastical Government Should Particularly be a Monarchy

St. Robert quotes Holy Scriptures much more copiously in support of these theses than can be summarized here; but—besides his Old Testament examples of monarchies, of Abraham, Moses, Aaron, et al. being monarchs, and the leaders of the twelve tribes being a prefiguration of the twelve Apostles—probably the single best Scriptural evidence of a monarchical constitution of the Church that St. Robert gives in ch. 9 is this part of John 10:16:

> John 10:16 …There will be one flock and one shepherd.

To which St. Robert commentates:

> Moreover, one sheepfold also requires one shepherd, as is gathered from the Gospel: “There will be one flock and one shepherd.” [John X.] It must be noted in passing, that “one shepherd” can be understood concerning a secondary pastor, namely Peter and his successors, as Cyprian expresses it. For when the Lord said he has other flocks and other sheep who are not of this fold, he speaks on the Gentile people and the people of the Jews: but he teaches that he has among the nations many elect, who either are already faithful, or certainly are going to be, and nevertheless they do not pertain to that Judaic people.
>
> If it is a question of the shepherd of God, the people of the Jews and gentiles were always one flock, and one God was their shepherd: nevertheless there was not always one flock and one shepherd with respect to the governance of the human race; nor indeed the gentiles, or those among them pertaining to the Church, ruled by the priest of the Jews. But Christ wished after his arrival, that one flock be made from each people, and all men to be governed by one shepherd.

and

> The similitude of the house and the boat remain, and indeed every house has one Lord and one steward, according to that of Luke’s gospel: “Who do you think is the faithful dispenser, and prudent, whom the Lord constituted over his household?” [Luke XII.] These words are said for Peter, and about Peter himself, since a little before the Lord had said to him: “Blessed are those servants, whom the Lord will discover watching when he will have come.” Peter asked: “O Lord, you speak to us this parable, can it be for all? The Lord responded to Peter: ‘Who do you think is the faithful and prudent dispenser? Whom the Lord constituted over his house?” It is just as if he were to say, where O Peter I say in the first place, it behooves you therefore to consider, what is required in a faithful and prudent steward, whom the Lord will establish over his household.

Chapters 1 through 4 are devoted to the question "What Might be the Best System of Government?" in which he shows that monarchy is simply the best, but "That Monarchy Mixed with Aristocracy and Democracy, Should be More Useful in this Life." He frequently quotes and refutes Calvin, who argued that aristocracy is better than monarchy even for ecclesiastical governance.

St. Robert's argument in a nutshell is:

1. Monarchy is the best.
2. God would not have chosen an inferior form of government for His Church.
3. Therefore, the Church is monarchical.

The Scripture from which he quoted or referenced in ch. 9: 1 Peter II. Matt. XVII. John I. Hebrews VIII. Job LX; Isaiah XIV. Ezechial XXVIII: 13. 1 Corinth. X. Song of Songs, VI. Ibid, VII. Daniel II; John I, 1 Timoth. III; 1 Peter III. Apoc. XXI; 2 Cor. XI; Ephes. V; often in the Song of Songs. Song of Songs VII. Ibid, V. John X. Luke XII. 1 Timothy 5. Romans X. Ephesians IV. 2 Cor. XI. Psalm XLIV. 1 Corinthians III. Psalm LXXXI. 2 Cor. XI. Daniel II: 37-38. Isaiah XLV:1. Luke II:1. 1 Cor. 3.

Comment: "**It must be noted in passing, that “one shepherd” can be understood concerning a secondary pastor, namely Peter and his successors ... For when the Lord said he has other flocks and other sheep who are not of this fold, he speaks on the Gentile people and the people of the Jews**" - Didn't quite get the logic behind this explanation. How does the fact of having two groups can mean that "One Pastor" in that passage of the Bible refers to Peter and his successors and not to the Lord Himself?

Comment: @brilliant What do you mean by "two groups"?

Comment: The Christians from among  the Jews and the Christians from among the Gentiles.

Comment: Well, that continuation doesn't seem to me to add much to the explanation, however, I think it is worthy to be appended to the quote in your answer.

Comment: @brilliant That was regarding John 10, but I added a ¶ on Luke 12, concerning the parable (v. 22 onward) Christ tells to his disciples and especially to St. Peter.

Answer (score 0):

Some hint may be in Mt 16,18-19: (NKJV)

> 18 And I also say to you that you are Peter, and on this rock I will
>   build My church, and the gates of Hades shall not prevail against it. 
>   19 And I will give you the keys of the kingdom of heaven, and whatever
>   you bind on earth will be bound in heaven, and whatever you loose on
>   earth will be loosed in heaven."

I'm aware that's not a sufficient answer, but it can be a good start.

Comment: St. Robert treats this in the third question of book 1 of his _De Romano Pontifice_ ([_On the Roman Pontiff_](http://mediatrixpress.com/?p=159)) ch. 10 ("A Third Question is Proposed, and the Monarchy of Peter is Proved from the Citation of the Gospel According to Matthew, Chapter XVI") ff.

Answer (score -1):

Acts 1:20 speaks of what to do with the office of a heretical bishop (Judas Iscariot in this particular case):

> For it is written in the book of Psalms <sup>[108:8]</sup>. ***Be their habitation made desert, and be there none to dwell in it. And his Bishopric* let another take.***

<sup>{*A bishopric can refer to the province of a bishop (diocese) or to his office.}</sup>

Thus, a heretical bishop is to be replaced, leaving only one bishop to occupy a bishopric at a time.

Comment: I don't understand. Peter applies these words to Judas Iscariot. Does this mean that Judas was a bishop?!

Comment: @brilliant Yes, the Apostles were bishops, but with some important differences (enumerated [here](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/04112a.htm)) compared to their successors.

Comment: "** Yes, the Apostles were bishops...**" - That article, the link to which you have provided, basis the idea of Apostolate-episcopate on the definition of the Apostles: "sent into the world a body of teachers and preachers after Jesus' mission was accomplished", however, Judas Iscariot was never among those whom He sent to teach all the nations baptizing them into the name of the Father, Son and the Holy Spirit.

Comment: @brilliant: Do you doubt St. Matthias, who replaced Judas, or the other successors of the Apostles were bishops? They weren't present at the Great Comission (Matt. 18:20). Also, Acts 1:15ff. shows St. Peter's first act of papal primacy in granting bishoprics.

Comment: "**Do you doubt Matthias, who replaced Judas, was a bishop?**" - I'm just trying to follow the logic of the definition in the article that you have cited. That article asserts the idea of apostles being bishops with a definition of apostles being the ones whom Jesus sent to teach and baptize all the nations after Jesus' mission was accomplished. Based on Acts 1:21 we can tell for sure that Matthias was among those sent ones, and, therefore, following the logic of the article, he is a bishop; however, Judas Iscariot was not among those whom Jesus was sending - he was already dead by then.

Comment: @brilliant So Judas wasn't even an Apostle when he was alive?

Comment: "**So Judas wasn't even an Apostle when he was alive?**" - Yes, he was. But he was not among those Apostles who, according to that article, became qualified to be bishops after the Lord's mission was accomplished.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24118/discussion-between-geremia-and-brilliant).

Comment: What does this have to do with there being only one bishop(rick) per each city ?